# Trying to make a new dataframe with details of an old one

Tags: python, dataframe

```
users = users.join(users.groupby('user_id').agg(
    user_orders= ('order_number' , max),
    user_period=('days_since_prior_order', sum),
    user_mean_days_since_prior = ('days_since_prior_order',mean)))


I keep getting errors... 
TypeError: category type does not support add operations
```

Can anyone help? im new to python

I was expecting something that looks like this

```
    user_orders user_period user_mean_days_since_prior
user_id         
1   10  176.0   19.562500
2   14  198.0   15.234375
3   12  133.0   12.093750
4   5   55.0    13.750000
5   4   40.0    13.335938
```

Comment: Looks like one of your columns contains categorical data and so can't be `sum`ed or `mean`ed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your original data? It will be easy to solve your problem once we know what data you have at hand. It looks like your data is not numeric, therefore some of the aggregate methods won't work.